# Display a block above text, but under the background?

Tags: html, css

How can I display a div below the background, but text that is above the background would take the same color as the div?

[This code](http://jsfiddle.net/kRRzg/1/) is what I have, but the pink div needs to be beneath the background, but still showing ontop of the text.

I was thinking of using

```
overflow: hidden
```

but since I have multiple buttons, I am not sure how to apply this.

Comment: you need z-index :) http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: Mind giving me an example? I've tried, but can't get it to work.

Comment: if the pink div was beneath the background - you wouldn't be able to see it at all.

Comment: @user2274691 here ya go. If I understood it right: http://jsfiddle.net/Nilzone/523ML/1/ (just play around with the z-index and see the different results)

Comment: Not exactly as I wanted. I know I can just hide the pink div behind the black background with z-index, but the problem here is that I want the yellow text to turn pink. I want it to be a div so I can easily move it with JavaScript, creating a sliding effect for when hovering over a button,

Comment: Is there a working example of this that you've seen before?

Comment: Nope, that is why I am asking if it is possible.